# How do i get google calendar descriptions to show in fullcalendar

Tags: fullcalendar, google-calendar-api

I would like to pull the description and location of my event from google calendar into fullCalendar. Ive got the time and title working fine, but I cant find anything to help me figure out how to show this other data. I've searched stackoverflow, but all related questions and answers are super old (like 2011).

If anyone could point me in the direct of a demo, or some documentation, or a question the solution to which still works I would be really grateful.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: " but all related questions and answers are super old "...did you try them anyway? Just because something's a few years old doesn't mean it doesn't work, some things don't change. Use the eventRender callback to alter your event's HTML so it includes the "description" field (which should be included in the event object already)